# How often is the ECCC queue cleared?

Tags: soft-question

I wanted to know as to how often are the submissions for ECCC cleared? Or do we know when is the next set of uploads going to be made on that site? Unlike arxiv where I know when my paper will go online, on ECCC there seems to be no way to know what is the timeline of my article. Last time I had submitted something on ECCC it took about 3 days for it go online. This time I am wondering as to why its taking longer. (..I had gone by this previous experience of 3 days to plan that I would refer to this online index number as reference for an upcoming talk of mine but now it seems I can't do that because the timeline looks indeterminate..)

---

If this is off-topic I will remove this. I guess people can just comment here rather than write "answers" so that I can eventually remove this question.

Comment: You try emailing them/

Comment: Whom? Is there any official id?

Comment: @JoshuaHerman: I have found them utterly unresponsive to email.

Comment: My understanding is that there is no formal schedule, but rather that the editorial staff gets notified when there's a submission and it is up to them as a collective to get around to each paper whenever they get to it, and (hopefully) make sure none fall through the cracks and take a long time. I'm not sure what internal system, if any, they have in place for the latter. If you really have a need for urgency you could try emailing an individual editor and hope they are sympathetic to your cause. Out of respect for their service, I wouldn't bug anyone until it's been at least a week.

Comment: That sounds like a plan. But is there a list of editors? Or any official representative? There is a scientific board listed at the end of this page, https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/colloquium/call_for_papers/

Comment: By "editor" I meant "member of the scientific board." in its current setup, these two things mean essentially the same thing for ECCC.

Answer (score 8):

Here is an excerpt from the [call for papers](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/colloquium/call_for_papers/) that explains the procedure:

> As soon as a submission arrives, several board members with expertise in its declared area are notified, and once a week all board members are sent the list of pending submissions. Board members may screen a submission at their own discretion, and make the decision whether or not to accept it. An accepted submission is posted as a report immediately. A submission is automatically rejected after two months if no board member accepted it.

The call for papers also lists the members of the board.

Comment: Yes. I had seen that. Though typically (or at least the last many papers I have seen there) seem to have a processing time of a few hours or a day or two at most. Therein lies my worry. (Also there is a stupid typo in my paper which I am unable to correct unless the paper goes up and I can then repost a correction. As of now in this state of limbo I can't even cancel the submission and re-submit a typo-free version. Its a catch-22!)

Comment: @gradstudent unless the typo turns your paper from a legit complexity paper into a total crackpot paper, it should not have an impact on its appearance in ECCC. They do not check for correctness, they just ensure a certain minimum quality of non-crackpottery.

Comment: No, that its not :D Its an issue with some mistyped variables in the abstract.  I believe the results are correct (and interesting!) :P

Comment: Now its been 9 days. I don't know whats going on. I see that the last paper there got online within 3 minutes of their submission!